# Generate a hash sum for several integers

Tags: hash

I am facing the problem of having several integers, and I have to generate one using them. For example.

```
Int 1: 14
Int 2: 4
Int 3: 8
Int 4: 4

Hash Sum: 43
```

I have some restriction in the values, the maximum value that and attribute can have is 30, the addition of all of them is always 30. And the attributes are always positive.

The key is that I want to generate the same hash sum for similar integers, for example if I have the integers, 14, 4, 10, 2 then I want to generate the same hash sum, in the case above 43. But of course if the integers are very different (4, 4, 2, 20) then I should have a different hash sum. Also it needs to be fast.

Ideally I would like that the output of the hash sum is between 0 and 512, and it should evenly distributed. With my restrictions I can have around 5K different possibilities, so what I would like to have is around 10 per bucket.

I am sure there are many algorithms that do this, but I could not find a way of googling this thing. Can anyone please post an algorithm to do this?.

**Some more information**

The whole thing with this is that those integers are attributes for a function. I want to store the values of the function in a table, but I do not have enough memory to store all the different options. That is why I want to generalize between similar attributes.

The reason why 10, 5, 15 are totally different from 5, 10, 15, it is because if you imagine this in 3d then both points are a totally different point

**Some more information 2**

Some answers try to solve the problem using hashing. But I do not think this is so complex. Thanks to one of the comments I have realized that this is a clustering algorithm problem. If we have only 3 attributes and we imagine the problem in 3d, what I just need is divide the space in blocks.

In fact this can be solved with rules of this type

```
if (att[0] < 5 && att[1] < 5 && att[2] < 5 && att[3] < 5)
     Block = 21


if ( (5 < att[0] < 10) &&  (5 < att[1] < 10) &&  (5 < att[2] < 10) &&  (5 < att[3] < 10))
     Block = 45
```

The problem is that I need a fast and a general way to generate those ifs I cannot write all the possibilities.

Comment: So you want a bad hash function? (high collision, non-even distribution)

Comment: I do not know how to use a hash function in my problem. For the hash function I need only one input and I have 4.

Comment: Ryan is right, what you are describing is bad input to a hash function. You should describe your problem, not a solution which you know doesn't work.

Comment: I still do not know why this is a bad input to a hash function, can you define what is bad input for a hash function?

Comment: As Eddie says, a hash function should "return a number evenly spread across the possible values"; given similar numbers it should produce different output. That is its purpose. What you are describing is the opposite.

Comment: Clustering similar values would be easy enough, if they could be clustered around pre-defined snap points. You seem to want dynamic snap points, which will require knowing all the other values.

Comment: @Ryan Graham, you are right this is exactly the same than clustering. Can you post this as an answer, to be more accessible for other users in the future. If you have experience in cluster can you please recommend a distance measure function, in fact I only need that.

Comment: Do you know all of the values ahead of time? A distance function won't help much if you don't have fixed values to measure. Perhaps you could offer more information on what the input and output numbers represent? I updated my answer based on guesses.

Comment: Have you had any luck on finding a solution? I am also trying to solve a similar question. In my case, I have a set of numbers represented in various forms (e.g. one set of numbers are in billions, the other one is in millions. One is in kilometers, the other one is in miles. One is obtained from a Wikipedia table, the other from another source. However, all represent the same concept. For example, GDP of countries.) I need a very robust technique that can capture the "semantics" of a set of numbers and decide whether they are similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the inputs a, b, c, and d, each ranging in value from 0 to 30 (5 bits), the following will produce an number in the range of 0 to 255 (8 bits).

```
bucket = ((a & 0x18) << 3) | ((b & 0x18) << 1) | ((c & 0x18) >> 1) | ((d & 0x18) >> 3)
```

Whether the general approach is appropriate depends on how the question is interpreted.  The 3 least significant bits are dropped, grouping 0-7 in the same set, 8-15 in the next, and so forth.

```
0-7,0-7,0-7,0-7 -> bucket 0
0-7,0-7,0-7,8-15 -> bucket 1
0-7,0-7,0-7,16-23 -> bucket 2
...
24-30,24-30,24-30,24-30 -> bucket 255
```

Trivially tested with:

```
for (int a = 0; a <= 30; a++)
    for (int b = 0; b <= 30; b++)
        for (int c = 0; c <= 30; c++)
            for (int d = 0; d <= 30; d++) {
                int bucket = ((a & 0x18) << 3) |
                             ((b & 0x18) << 1) |
                             ((c & 0x18) >> 1) |
                             ((d & 0x18) >> 3);
                printf("%d, %d, %d, %d -> %d\n",
                         a,  b,  c,  d,   bucket);
            }
```

Comment: Hi that method is nice but the problem is that I need the same buckets for similar states, for example 11,10,5,4 and 11,10,5,3, should have the same bucket. I cannot have 15, 15, 15, 15 and 0, 0, 0, 0 with the same bucket. Maybe I should open a new more clear quetion this one is totally messy now.

Comment: It is getting a little comical, ya... I can add another example now that you've specified your ranges though.

Comment: Did you test that?, it does not work, this is part of the distribution, attending to the possible options for the attributes . 0  84  344  83  84  344  84  0  344  84  0  0  83  0  0  0  84  344  84  0  344  84  0  0  84  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  344  84  0  0  84  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  83

Comment: Hi, there was a little of misunderstanding, you code works fine when the attributes are from 0 to 30, BUT I have the condition that the addition of all of them is 30, when you introduce that condition then I get the output I said before.

Comment: Hi, there was a little of misunderstanding, you code works fine when the attributes are from 0 to 30, BUT I have the condition that the addition of all of them is 30, when you introduce that condition then I get the output I said before.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan for your help, I have not come up with an easy way of solve this problem but I am sure that there is a way in do what I am looking for in a very simple way.

Answer (score 5):

**The simple solution:**

Convert the integers to strings separated by commas, and hash the resulting string using a common hashing algorithm (md5, sha, etc).

**If you really want to roll-your-own, I would do something like:**

- Generate large prime P
- Generate random numbers 0 < a[i] < P (for each dimension you have)

To generate hash, calculate: sum(a[i] * x[i]) mod P

Comment: +1 for integers -> string ("1 2 3") -> hash - it works well and is relatively efficient

Answer (score 2):

You want a hash function that depends on the order of inputs and where similar sets of numbers will generate the same hash?  That is, you want 50 5 5 10 and 5 5 10 50 to generate different values, but you want 52 7 4 12 to generate the same hash as 50 5 5 10?  A simple way to do something like this is:

```
long hash = 13;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    hash = hash * 37 + array[i] / 5;
}
```

This is imperfect, but should give you an idea of one way to implement what you want.  It will treat the values 50 - 54 as the same value, but it will treat 49 and 50 as different values.

If you want the hash to be independent of the order of the inputs (so the hash of 5 10 20 and 20 10 5 are the same) then one way to do this is to sort the array of integers into ascending order before applying the hash.  Another way would be to replace

```
    hash = hash * 37 + array[i] / 5;
```

with

```
    hash += array[i] / 5;
```

**EDIT:**  Taking into account your comments in response to this answer, it sounds like my attempt above may serve your needs well enough.  It won't be ideal, nor perfect.  If you need high performance you have some research and experimentation to do.

To summarize, order is important, so 5 10 20 differs from 20 10 5.  Also, you would ideally store each "vector" separately in your hash table, but to handle space limitations you want to store some groups of values in one table entry.

An ideal hash function would return a number evenly spread across the possible values based on your table size.  Doing this right depends on the expected size of your table and on the number of and expected maximum value of the input vector values.  If you can have negative values as "coordinate" values then this may affect how you compute your hash.  If, given your range of input values and the hash function chosen, your maximum hash value is less than your hash table size, then you need to change the hash function to generate a larger hash value.

Comment: What other information do you need?. The whole thing with this is that those integers are attributes for a function. I want to store the values of the function in a table, but I do not have enough memory to store all the different options. That is why I want to generalize between similar attributes.

Comment: The reason why 10, 5, 15 are totally different from 5, 10, 15, it is because if you imagine this in 3d then both points are a totally different point.

Comment: @Eduardo: Please edit your question to add the above information to the question itself.  This will help people reading your question understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using [vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector) to describe each number set as the hash value.

EDIT:
Since you're not describing why you want to not run the function itself, I'm guessing it's long running. Since you haven't described the breadth of the argument set.

If every value is expected then a full lookup table in a database might be faster.

If you're expecting repeated calls with the same arguments and little overall variation, then you could look at [memoizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) so only the first run for a argument set is expensive, and each additional request is fast, with less memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define what you mean by "similar". Hashes are generally designed to create unique results from unique input.

One approach would be to normalize your input and then generate a hash from the results.

Comment: What you mean with normalize?

Answer (score 0):

Generating the same hash sum is called a collision, and is a bad thing for a hash to have. It makes it less useful.

If you want similar values to give the same output, you can divide the input by however close you want them to count. If the order makes a difference, use a different divisor for each number. The following function does what you describe:

```
int SqueezedSum( int a, int b, int c, int d )
{
    return (a/11) + (b/7) + (c/5) + (d/3);
}
```

This is not a hash, but does what you describe.

Comment: In my case the collisions if they are controlled are good, because is how I am doing the generalization in the function

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into [geometric hashing](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-01-winter/papers/wr-ghao-97.pdf). In "standard" hashing you want

1. a short key
2. inverse resistance
3. collision resistance

With geometric hashing you susbtitute number 3 with something whihch is almost opposite; namely close initial values give close hash values.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to view my problem is using the multidimesional scaling (MS). In MS we start with a matrix of items and what we want is assign a location of each item to an N dimensional space. Reducing in this way the number of dimensions.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling